# Confusing Property Delegation in Gradle's Kotlin DSL

Tags: kotlin, gradle, gradle-kotlin-dsl

Below is the code snippet that I came across in gradle's documentation
**https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/tutorial_using_tasks.html**

```
val hello by tasks.registering {
    doLast {
        println("Hello Earth")
    }
}
hello {
    doFirst {
        println("Hello Venus")
    }
}
```

In the above, *hello* is a TaskProvider type which provides task definition/action. The second call to hello is to extend the behavior of the task.

This *delegate* use looks slightly confusing to me. Following are the questions which are bugging me:

1) On inspecting the decompiled byte-code, I see *tasks.registering* returns **RegisteringDomainObjectDelegateProviderWithAction** object which should be used as the delegate and hence should provide getValue() and setValue() methods for *delegate* to work but as I saw, methods are not provided. Instead the class **RegisteringDomainObjectDelegateProviderWithAction** has a **delegateProvider** property of type *tasks* which is supposed to provide the *delegate*. Can any one help me understand, how delegation works here?

2) The second call is supposed to add behavior to the *hello* task. Since *hello* is a property, how are we able to pass a lambda/behavior to it? What am I missing?

I have already seen kotlin documentation which provides good explanation of delegates but doesn't aid in understanding the above case *https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/delegated-properties.html*

I would appreciate a detailed explanation as I am new to Kotlin.

Comment: For the second call you can look for operator overloading. See: [`operator fun invoke()`](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/operator-overloading.html#invoke)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. **Regarding the delegate use:**

   The delegation works via an extension operator method `provideDelegate` defined on `RegisteringDomainObjectDelegateProviderWithAction`:

   ```
   operator fun RegisteringDomainObjectDelegateProviderWithAction<out TaskContainer, Task>.provideDelegate(
       receiver: Any?,
       property: KProperty<*>
   ) = ExistingDomainObjectDelegate.of(
       delegateProvider.register(property.name, action)
   )
   ```

   The `provideDelegate` operator allows for more complex logic in delegate creation. As per the [docs](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/delegated-properties.html#providing-a-delegate-since-11):

   > By defining the `provideDelegate` operator you can extend the logic of creating the object to which the property implementation is delegated. If the object used on the right hand side of by defines `provideDelegate` as a member or extension function, that function will be called to create the property delegate instance.
2. **Regarding the "passing a lambda to a property":**

   This is implemented via overloading of the [`invoke` operator](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/operator-overloading.html#invoke) as an extension function on the `TaskProvider` class:

   ```
   operator fun <T> NamedDomainObjectProvider<T>.invoke(action: T.() -> Unit) =
       configure(action)
   ```

   Basically, the call `hello { /* your lambda */ }` is desugared into `hello.invoke { /* your lambda */ }`.